# Filtering array based on select list and deleting a field not working

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

please help me how to change my code to be able to filter an array based on drop down selection, then deleting a field from an array.

Code is uploaded here: http://jsfiddle.net/x8e3rvcj

It works if I select first and second list item but returms empty array after third/fourth selection, seems because of deleting a field in the result array.
If I remove the deletion part the selection works properly.

Deletion part seems causing issue is:

```
finalArray = jQuery.each(finalArray, function(arrElem, arrValue) {
Delete arrValue.MID; 
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Filter works as expected, something is messing up the code in the onchange function when I try to delete a field from the result array of the filter. I just try to figure out why and how to do the deletion then within the onchange event?

Comment: Use `splice()` to remove an element from array. Can get it's index easily using indexOf()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day searching what I found is that copying / editing arrays in javascript impacts any copy of the array in scope.
This is called mutating.

Solution: don't simply copy an array but "deep" copy it:

```
let copyArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(valueArr)); //... etc.
```

Thanks whoever invented this annoying concept for my extra time spent on this code part!